# how they went from $E(1,|X−Y|>1)=0$ to $P(|X−Y|>1)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Consider the following mathematical statements involving random variables $X$ and $Y$:

The notation $|X-Y|\wedge 1$ denotes the minimum of $|X-Y|$ and 1.

$
\begin{align*}
E(|X-Y|\wedge 1)=0 &\implies E(|X-Y|, |X-Y|\leq 1) + E(1, |X-Y| > 1) = 0 \\
&\implies E(|X-Y|, |X-Y|\leq 1) = 0 \text{ and } P(|X-Y| > 1) = 0 \\
&\implies E(|X-Y|) = E(|X-Y|, |X-Y|\leq 1) = 0 \\
&\implies X=Y \text{ almost surely.}
\end{align*}
$

I have two specific questions regarding the above statements:

1. how they went from $E(1,|X−Y|>1)=0$  to $P(|X−Y|>1)=0$
2. Similarly, why is it true that $E(|X-Y|) = E(|X-Y|, |X-Y|\leq 1)$?

I would appreciate any explanations or insights into these equalities. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify what you meant with $E(|X-Y|\wedge 1)$ at the beginning of the post?

Comment: Long story short, the two equalities in your two specific questions are false. However the reasoning as a whole is not really false, just not very detailed ;-)

Comment: @Stef  The notation \(|X-Y|\wedge 1\) denotes the minimum of \(|X-Y|\) and 1.

Comment: For instance they went from $E(|X-Y|, |X-Y| > 1) = 0$ to  $P(|X-Y| > 1) = 0$, not because $E(|X-Y|, |X-Y| > 1) =  P(|X-Y| > 1)$ (that's not true) but by contraposition of: if $P(|X-Y| > 1) > 0$, then $E(|X-Y|, |X-Y| > 1) > 1$.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing your question to clarify this, then. $\wedge$ is a supercharged symbol in mathematics, so if you don't explain what it means in the post, readers have to guess. Personally I went through "logical conjunction (and)", "placeholder symbol that can be $<$ or $>$ respectively" and "greatest common divisor" before I even thought about "minimum".

Comment: @Stef  Thank you so the question is could someone could elaborate more how did goes from line 1 to line 2

Answer (score 1):

The steps in your post seem to be a little out of order.

We have the following two equalities.
\begin{align}
E[|X-Y|] &= E[|X-Y|, |X-Y| \le 1] + E[|X-Y|, |X-Y| > 1] \tag{a}\\
E[|X-Y| \land 1] &= E[|X-Y|, |X-Y| \le 1] + E[1, |X-Y| > 1]\tag{b}
\end{align}

If $E[|X-Y| \land 1] = 0$, then both terms on the right-hand side of (b) must be zero. Note that $E[1, |X-Y|>1]$ can be rewritten as $P(|X-Y| > 1)$.

Since $P(|X-Y|>1)=0$, we have $E[|X-Y|, |X-Y| > 1] = 0$.

We have shown that the two terms on the right-hand side of (a) are both zero, so we have $E[|X-Y|]=0$.

Comment: thank you , but why do we have "Since $P(|X-Y|>1)=0$, we have $E[|X-Y|, |X-Y| > 1] = 0$." is it proposition ? and why $E[1, |X-Y|>1]=P(|X-Y| > 1)$ is it formula .

Comment: @IvanGozard Maybe you should revisit the definition of $E[Z, A]$ for a random variable $Z$ and an event $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Any recommended resources to better understand E[Z,A]? Appreciate it!

Comment: Any recommended resources to better understand E[Z,A]?